# Difference between replace and replaceAll

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

What is the difference between `replace` and `replaceAll` methods of the string?

In following example, code gives `same` output. In both cases `all` instances of the string are replaced.

```
String first = "Here is a cat There is a cat";
first = first.replace("cat", "dog"); 
System.out.println(first);
```

Output:

> Here is a dog There is a dog

```
String second = "Here is a cat There is a cat";
second = second.replaceAll("cat", "dog"); 
System.out.println(second);
```

Output:

> Here is a dog There is a dog

Comment: did you read the javadocs?

Comment: Clearly explained: [replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) , [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3):

```
 String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the *literal target sequence* with the specified literal replacement sequence.

```
String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given *regular expression* with the given replacement.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html